# Can't enable error messages for PHP on my web server

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I'm trying to disable error messages for PHP on my Apache2 web server, but it's not working.

I have enabled it in the `php.ini` file.

`error_reporting = E_ALL`

I deliberately introduced errors in my test.php script, and in the script itself, I have included the following, but no errors are displayed.

```
init_set('display_errors', 1);
init_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using, and what is the path to your php.ini file?

Comment: this is my file /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

The `php.ini` file, located at `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini`, is only responsible for the command line interface.

If you use the `echo phpinfo();` function in a script to display your configuration, you will see the following lines:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path
Loaded Configuration File
```

The lines will show the path as `/etc/php/7.3/apache2` and `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` for your Apache2 web server.

To edit the configuration for your Apache2 web server, you need to modify the file `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini`.

So, there are `two php.ini` files available.